# Is a this a typo in this Jinja2 example, or am I missing something?

Tags: flask, jinja2

```
<p>
        Please enter your OpenID, or select one of the providers below:<br>
        {{ form.openid(size=80) }}
        {% for error in form.openid.errors %}
          <span style="color: red;">[{{error}}]</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
        |{% for pr in providers %}
          <a href="javascript:set_openid('{{ pr.url }}', '{{ pr.name }}');">{{ pr.name }}</a> |
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
```

I'm going through [the Flask mega-tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms) and am building out this basic form here, but am confused by the presence of two `|` characters in the template with no explanation, around *part* but not all of a for loop, as you can see.

My understanding was that the pipe character is used for filtering in jinja templates, which isn't what appears to be happening here.

What am I missing? Or is this just a botched example?

Comment: What makes you think it is botched? The template *works*, and throws no errors. The `|` characters are not inside `{{..}}` or `{%..%}` elements, so why should Jinja2 care about those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not part of any Jinja syntax, it's just a character that will be rendered by the template.  Try rendering that template, you'll see that all it's doing is printing pipes as separators between the links.